# SQL Server trigger latency?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created a trigger for a table in SQL Server 2008

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_mytable
ON dbo.mytable

FOR INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE

AS 

EXTERNAL NAME mycode.[trig.mytable].myfn
```

The code for `mytable.myfn` is in C#. It opens a connection to the database and queries the inserted or deleted table based on the event to get the trigger data. Can it be possible that an entry is inserted and immediately deleted (in like a fraction of a second or say ms) from the table and the trigger function is never called? In short can there be a latency or absence of trigger? My understanding is that triggers use interrupt sort of mechanism rather than polling. I am very new to SQL Server and triggers.

Answer (score 2):

No: there is no latency or lag

The trigger is part of the INSERT and DELETE statement. 
When the trigger completes, then SQL Server reports the INSERT or DELETE as complete

Note: you'd typically keep triggers short and concise and not use external code or calls

Comment: So the trigger is sort of a dependency for the INSERT or DELETE to be executed? And hence it is not possible to bypass the calling of the trigger code and insert/delete into the table, right?

Comment: @Lalitha: yes, you can think of of it as a dependency. No, it can not be bypassed normally (unless some disables the trigger: but this requires elevated permissions that shouldn't be given to end users)

Comment: @Lalitha: Check the FAQ about accepting and voting answers. If I've helped you, please accept this answer using the big tick on the left